# How does this webpage load data dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-services

I found a webpage which I thought was using ajax to load data dynamically, but I see with inspector that there are no requests done when hitting the "load more" button at the bottom of the page. Im wondering what technique this page is using? Any expert which can figure it out? Also, I can not find any of the content that seems to be loaded dynamically preloaded in the dom. So question is, where does the dynamically loaded content come from? Any help would be appreaciated.

"Hent flere" is the same as "Load more" in norwegian.

URL:
https://helsenorge.no/min-helse/Bytte-fastlege?fylke=02&kommuner=0220

Comment: What do you mean by _"dynamically loaded content"_?

Comment: it first shows a limited lists of doctors, then when you click the "Hent flere" button, it shows you more doctors, but I cant seem to find where it loads these doctor names from, no ajax requests are made, and i cant find the names within any js-files.

Comment: initially, 15 doctor names are shown. when I click the "Hent flere" button at the bottom, 15 more doctors are loaded, but in a mystical way I cant understand, as there is no new requests made.

Comment: Probably the page has loaded everything during the initial request, thus you don't see any more request when you hit on load more.

Comment: The button has several `click` handlers attached. Additional content appears to be animated to a visible state when the button is clicked. See https://helsenorge.no/_layouts/15/hn.minhelse.sp/ByttFastlege/vendors.js?rev=636004165519992350:formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all loaded via ajax when the page loads. The URL is : https://helsenorge.no/_vti_bin/portal/rest.svc/execute?cmd=AvtaleSok

It loads everything in one go then displays only part of it. It should be able to display the rest immediately when you press "load more" but I guess the designer wanted the animated dots to look fancy.

Comment: Than I was mistaken. It was loaded initially. I thought I had searched every file, but obviously not :) Thanks for the fast respond.

Comment: I see its not possible to call the url directly, it needs to have headers set, maybe cookie... etc

Comment: When all else fails there's always phantom.js :D

Comment: @slebetman , This url is not returning much data just a one item array that's it.

Comment: @cafebabe1991: The server checks referrer to disallow the URL to be used on other web pages. To see the data open the developer tools in your browser. Go the the page the OP linked. Find the XHR request to the URL I posted in the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

There are different way:

1) WebSockets can load data end send data (in both directions) and they work in RealTime.

2) SSE are Server Send Events, that can push data from the server in realtime (but they usually appears in the inspector... i guess)

3) Adding a script that is added by an other script with refreshed content. (Kind of a workaround, for those who don't want to use Ajax for some Reason)

4) Hidden frame trick: iFrame can communicate with the parent trough window.parent or postMessage. With a refresh header it would be ease to update the parent window

Hope you find for what you are looking for ;)